# display 'The user name or password is incorrect.' error in Login

Tags: angular, typescript, http

so I want to console.log "The user name or password is incorrect." message when the user types the wrong credentials. My problem is that I don't know how to do it exactly. Any suggestions?

Here is my Error Interceptor :

```
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private authenticationService:AuthenticationService) {}

    intercept(request:HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler) : Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status===401) {
                // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                this.authenticationService.logout();
                location.reload(true);
            }

            const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

and here is my login component :

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted=true;
    if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
      console.log("invalid");
      return;
    }
    this.loading=true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value,this.f.password.value)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe({
      next : () => {
        //get return url from route parameter or default to '/'
        const returnUrl= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
        this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
      }
    });
    

  }
```

Here is the API response I get when I type the wrong password :

[image: API HTTP Response]

A help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

A simple component property would do if you aren't using `OnPush`, but here's how to dot it `OnPush` safe. I always recommend using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` anyway.

```
// component.ts
error$ = new BehaviorSubject(''); // import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs'

// service call
  .subscribe({
      next: () => { 
        this.error$.next('');
        // Navigate
      },
      error: err => { 
        this.error$.next(err?.error_description || 'Unknown Error')
      }
  })
```

```
<!-- component.html -->
<div *ngIf="error$ | async as error">
   {{ error }}
</div>
```

Of course there are other things you could do. You could display an alert, or a dialog or SnackBar from @angular/material, etc. Up to you.

Comment: I appreciate your help @funkizer ,but the div displays "unnkown error" instead of "wrong user Name or Password", i want it to display exactly what the API response says, any idea how to do it ?